# Rails: AJAX pagination with Kaminari gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I have a Rails application and I am trying to add pagination with [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari).

I have a controller action like this.

```
def index
  ..
  @hotels = Kaminari.paginate_array(@hotels).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  ..
end
```

My index.html.haml

```
  ...
    .homestay-rightside.hotel-rightside
      = render :partial => 'hotel_rightside', :locals => {:hotels => @hotels}
  ...
```

My hotel_rightside partial

```
  - if hotels.present?
    #hotels_listing  
      = render :partial => 'hotel_details', :locals => {:hotels => @hotels}
    #hotels_pagination
      = paginate @hotels, :remote => true
```

My index.js.erb

```
   $('#hotels_listing').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "hotel_details", :locals => {:hotels => @hotels }) %>');
   $('#hotels_pagination').html("<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@hotels, :remote => true)) %>");
```

Right now it makes an HTML request even though I have added remote true.

How can I make it into an ajax request ?

Comment: Hope this can help you: http://nhattan.github.io/rails/pagination/2015/06/26/remote-pagination-with-kaminari.html

Comment: Inside `hotel_rightside` partial, you have `hotel_details` partial right?? But why you are refreshing only `hotel_details` here in `index.js.erb` ?? `$('#hotels_listing').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "hotel_details", :locals => {:hotels => @hotels }) %>')`

Comment: I have updated the js.erb as I had wrongly used haml syntax in erb.
Even after that it didn't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using custom kaminari views in your project so look into your views and find out if this `:remote => remote` present or not if not then add it in `link_to_unless` helper options.

**e.g.**

```
= link_to_unless page.current?, page, url, {:rel => page.next? ? 'next' : page.prev? ? 'prev' : nil , :class => "page-link", :remote => remote}
```

Comment: Yes you are right Amit. It worked only after making the change suggested by you. Thanks a lot !